# How can I send commands to a remote X11 session?

Tags: ssh, xorg, raspberrypi, xrandr

I have a remote Raspberry Pi connected to an old display. The Raspberry Pi is not configured correctly to display to this old display (it is basically sending the wrong resolution signal to the display). I need to troubleshoot this while the old display is connected to the Raspberry Pi.

To do this, I have connected via SSH (with X11 forwarding enabled) to the Raspberry Pi. I now need to send `xrandr` (and similar commands) to the Raspberry Pi and to have those commands apply to the remote X11 session running on the Raspberry Pi, as opposed to the X11 session running on my local computer.

When I run `xrandr -q`, `xrandr -s 640x480` etc. in the terminal while connected via SSH to the Raspberry Pi, the commands apply to the local X11 session when I need them to apply to the remote X11 session. How can I do this?

Comment: Try the other way - *disable* X11 forwarding, and set `DISPLAY` to whatever it is when logged in directly to the Pi's GUI (`:0`, probably)